# VBA in notepad to run code in Excel error

Tags: vba, excel

This is the code I have saved in Notepad.  Do I need to change Excel.Applications?

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp
Dim xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("H:\shane.xlsm", 0, True)

xlApp.Run "Email"
xlBook.close
xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = nothing
```

This is the code I have to send the email and when I test it works fine and will send me an email.

```
Option Explicit

Const strTo As String = "dvandervieren@enerplus.com"
Const strCC As String = ""  '<~~ change "def@abc.com" to "" if you do not want to CC
Const strBCC As String = "" '<~~ change "ghi@abc.com" to "" if you do not want to BCC

Sub Email()
Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String, strSubject As String

strSubject = "Hello World"
strbody = "This is the message for the body"

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .To = strTo
    .CC = strCC
    .BCC = strBCC
    .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
    .Body = strbody
    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Post your code to shows us what you're trying that is failing.

Comment: Put the macro in the Excel workbook instead of Notepad.

Comment: Is that the easiest way to control a macro in another woorkbook?

Comment: I just tried to run the code out of another workbook and it is still showing a runtime error (1004) on line 6 'xlApp.Run "Email"

Comment: Probably because you have an error in your Email macro and it doesn't have its own error-handling and reporting.

Comment: Try `xlBook.Email` instead... Where is the Email macro stored?

Comment: The macro is stored in Excell to send the email.  the code to run the macro in excel is in notepad

Comment: You cannot store Macros "in Excel". A macro in Excel is always attached to a workbook. Eithr within a module, or stored within the code for one of the Microsoft Excel Objects. The location of the code may matter. If `Email` isn't in a standard module then Excel won't find it the way you're trying to call it. Did you try my suggestion? If you can pinpoint the object to which `Email` is attached, you can simply call it directly without `Application.Run`.

Comment: I am new to VBA so I am still trying to understand this all.  The code is save under sheet 1 of my vba project (I dont know if that helps).  What is a standard module that I need to save the code in?  I replaced xlApp.Run "email" with xlBook.Email and I still got an error.  How would I find the Object for "email"?

Comment: @David Van der Vieren  Open Your excel document. Open the VB Editor. Find the excel document in the left hand window pane.  Right click and select Insert>>Module.  Move your code into the newly created module. You should then be able to call it using just the method name Email.  You do not need to delcare an excel application as you are already inside of excel.

Comment: Awsome it worked!  Just need it to delete a runtime error code, but it is sending a message.  Thanks to everyone for helping, I am learning alot.

Answer (score 0):

Open Your excel document. Open the VB Editor. Find the excel document in the left hand window pane. Right click and select Insert>>Module. Move your code into the newly created module. You should then be able to call it using just the method name Email. You do not need to delcare an excel application as you are already inside of excel. –  [Sorceri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1586390/sorceri)

Comment: Community wiki.  Answer is in a comment. Anyone finding this topic in a search will see there is an answer and is more likely to look in for a hopefully useful answer.